# How to create a view that need to display complete application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, user-interaction

I need a view that need to be common for application.I am adding the view to new uiwindow,because the view should not navigate to other screen,it needs to be common.That is reason i am setting on separate uiwindow as per reference of [http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/multiple-uiwindows/] .But here is the actual problem.I am adding a button on top of new UIwindow and unable to select ,because user interaction disabled for it.Added the code below.

```
topWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 200)];
[topWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelAlert];
[topWindow setRootViewController:viewController];
[topWindow setHidden:NO];
[topWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

If i set `topWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` then i am unable to touch main window.
I want some thing like user interaction enabled for topWindow button and i need user interaction for main UIWindow too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.Sorry for the late answer.

I have done this with the help of Container View in iOS.Created a fake view controller with container view and added the fake view controller to the root view controller.It works like charm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to create a UIWindow?  When I have an alert that may appear any time, without regard to view hierarchy, I just add a UIView as a subview of the main UIWindow, without any UIViewController.  Maybe that will work for you.